# how to convert png to svg using apache batik in java?

Tags: java, spring

i want to convert my png image file into svg and store in file system, i not found any apropriate answer if anyone have the solution please share.

i use below code but not work
SVGTranscoder t = new SVGTranscoder();

```
    t.addTranscodingHint(SVGTranscoder.KEY_FORMAT, true);

    String svgURI = new File(inputFilePath).toURL().toString();

    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFilePath);
    Reader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
    TranscoderInput input = new TranscoderInput(inputStreamReader);

    OutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(outputFilePath);
    Writer outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(ostream);
    TranscoderOutput output = new TranscoderOutput(outputStreamWriter);

    t.transcode(input, output);

    ostream.flush();
    ostream.close();
    System.exit(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Converter converter = new Converter("input.png");
// Prepare conversion options for target format SVG
ConvertOptions convertOptions = new FileType().fromExtension("svg").getConvertOptions();
// Convert to SVG format
converter.convert("output.svg", convertOptions);
```

Comment: can you give the maven repository for this?

Comment: `<dependency>
    <groupId>com.groupdocs</groupId>
    <artifactId>groupdocs-conversion</artifactId>
    <version>17.12</version>
</dependency>`

Comment: if facing issues add this too to your pom.xml file

`<repositories>

 <repository>

  <id>GroupDocsJavaAPI</id>

  <name>GroupDocs Java API</name>

  <url>http://repository.groupdocs.com/repo/</url>

 </repository>

</repositories>`

Comment: both are open source?

Comment: Yes groupdocs is open source . 
And the above two are same . One you have to add under Repository and other under dependencies 
GroupDocs is an open source api for file Conversions.

Comment: Rest if you face any issues in installation . You can go through the guide for installation provided by GroupDocs
[Group-Docs](https://docs.groupdocs.com/conversion/java/installation/)

Comment: it is working but in converted svg file the watermark of groupdocs is there, can we remove it?